# How to animate NSLayoutConstraint without IBOutlet

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, iad

I have a View Controller containing a view (of another controller) and a tab bar at the bottom. I want to add an iAD banner such that when an ad is loaded and unloaded, the contained view is resized accordingly.

```
/* AutoLayout */
/* pin Left of child to left of parent */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:child.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeft
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];

/* pin Right of child to right of parent */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:child.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeRight
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];

/* pin top of child to bottom of nav bar(or status bar if no nav bar) */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:child.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.topLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];


/* pin Top of tab bar to bottom of child view */
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomLayoutGuide
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:child.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:0]];


/* 
 * adConstraint is an instance variable to hold the constraint I want to animate
 * Note that it is not an IBOutlet
 */
adConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:child.view
                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                            relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                               toItem:self.view
                                            attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                           multiplier:1.0
                                             constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:adConstraint];
```

In my delegate methods i have the following

```
- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        adConstraint.constant = -banner.frame.size.height;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

and

```
- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        adConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

I seriously need help with this! Is it even possible to achieve this without Storyboard and the IBOutlet or am I doing something (terribly) wrong?

Please Help?!

*************************** EDIT: ****************************

I've noticed a problem; The ad shows up but bannerDidLoadAd is not called. I know this because I added log statements in it. Does anyone know why this might be happening????

Comment: What result does the code you posted give? Did you set your controller as the delegate of the banner view?

Comment: Yes I did. What is odd is that an ad appears on the screen but the log gives this error - "Unhandled error (no delegate or delegate does not implement didFailToReceiveAdWithError:): Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=7" and the bannerDidLoadAd does not get called and the constraints don't change ... but theres an ad on my screen

Comment: Also just so you know, I create the banner in viewDidLoad then call `_iAdBanner.delegate = self` then call `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES`. Am i supposed to mess with the `self.canDisplayBannerAds` property

Comment: You probably don't have the delegates set up properly. Fix that first. You haven't shown any constant with your banner variable. How do you add it? Subview to self.view? if you wan't it to now show up you have to either hide it by [banner setHidden:0] or set the constraints accordingly so it resize with the rest.

Comment: Is there anything I need to do besides setting `_iAdBanner.delegate = self` and adding `<IADBannerViewDelegate>` to the interface header to set up my delegates? Also its not that I want to hide the banner, its that I want to change the constraints when it is shown or hidden and it does not work. Also what did you mean by I haven't shown any constant with the banner variable

Answer (score 0):

Try calling

```
[self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
```

before

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

It should work!

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        adConstraint.constant = 0;
        [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```